# How to print a number of boxes inside eachother in C

Tags: c

I am currently doing a computer science course and am finding it very hard to complete a challenge question! It is meant to read in a number and then draws that many square boxes inside each other using the character # with Spaces filling the gaps in between = for example:

How many boxes: 3

```
#######
#     #
# ### #
# # # #
# ### #
#     #
#######
```

How many boxes: 5

```
###################
#                 #
# ############### #
# #             # #
# # ########### # #
# # #         # # #
# # # ####### # # #
# # # #     # # # #
# # # # ### # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
# # # # ### # # # #
# # # #     # # # #
# # # ####### # # #
# # #         # # #
# # ########### # #
# #             # #
# ############### #
#                 #
###################
```

If someone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated! This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int row, column;
    int n;

    printf("How many boxes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int sideLength;
    sideLength = n * 3 + 1;

    row = 0;
    while(row < sideLength){
        column = 0;
        while(column < sideLength){
            if(row == 0 || row == sideLength - 1){
                printf("#"); 
            }
            else if(column % 2 != 0){
                printf(" ");
            }
            else if(column % 2 == 0 && row % 2 == 1){
                printf(" ");
            }
            else if(column == 0 || column == sideLength - 1 ){
                printf("#");
            }
            else if(column % 2 == 0 && row % 2 == 0){
                printf("#");
            }
            column++;
        }
        printf("%d", column);
        printf("\n");
        row++;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it has been asked before.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The first pattern in only 2 squares though...

Comment: Also, I believe the formula should be `(n * 3) + (n - 1)`

Comment: The guys at [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) would love that challange!

Comment: I would have used a totally different approach: allocate an arbitrary size 2D array (eg: char raster[100][100]) in memory and "draw" the boxes in it using 2D coordinates. Then print it in output row-by-row. I don't know if you are starting to master arrays, thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int boxes = 0;
    printf("How many boxes: ");
    scanf("%d", &boxes);
    int size = ((boxes * 3) + (boxes - 1));
    int i = 1; // Row counter
    int j = 1; // Column counter
    int mid_row = boxes * 2;

    // For printing each row
    while (i <= size) {
        j = 1;
        if (i < mid_row) {
            // For printing each column
            while (j <= size) {

                // If the current row is odd
                if ((i % 2) != 0) {

                    // If the current column is odd
                    if ((j % 2) != 0) {
                        printf("#");
                    } else {
                        // If the current column is even
                        if ((j < i) || ((size - j) < i)) {
                            printf(" ");
                        } else {
                            printf("#");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // If the current row is even

                    // If the current column is odd
                    if ((j % 2) != 0) {
                        if ((j < i) || ((size - j) < i)) {
                            printf("#");
                        } else {
                            printf(" ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        // If the current column is even
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }
        } else if (i == mid_row) {
            while (j <= size) {
                if ((j % 2) != 0) {
                    printf("#");
                } else {
                    printf(" ");
                };
                j++;
            }
        } else {
            // For printing each column
            while (j <= size) {

                // If the current row is odd
                if ((i % 2) != 0) {

                    // If the current column is odd
                    if ((j % 2) != 0) {
                        printf("#");
                    } else {
                        // If the current column is even
                        if ((j > i) || ((size - j) >= i)) {
                            printf(" ");
                        } else {
                            printf("#");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // If the current row is even

                    // If the current column is odd
                    if ((j % 2) != 0) {
                        if ((j > i) || ((size - j) >= i)) {
                            printf("#");
                        } else {
                            printf(" ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        // If the current column is even
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }
                j++;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, but first you have to correctly evalute the length of the printed side of the biggest square.

```
sideLength = n * 3 + 1;
```

Is wrong, it produces the sequence {4, 7, 10, ...}, while it should be {3, 7, 11, ...}, because the smallest square is 3 chars wide and they grow by 4 chars (a `' '` and a `'#'` at both sides) at every step.

Then you can take advantage of the symmetry of the requested shape and split the drawing into smaller parts inside a function

```
void draw_boxes(int n) {
    const char *stroke = "# ";

    if ( n < 1 )
        return;

    int side = 4 * n - 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < side; ++row) {
        int col = 0;
        // Precalculate the boundaries
        int left = row;
        int right = side - row;
        if ( left > right ) {
            left = right;
            right = row;
        }
        // Left side, alternate '#' with ' '
        for (; col < left; ++col) {
            putchar(stroke[col % 2]);
        }
        // Horizontal line, all '#' or ' ' 
        char ch = stroke[row % 2];
        for (; col < right; ++col) {
            putchar(ch);
        }
        // Right side, same as left side
        for (; col < side; ++col) {
            putchar(stroke[col % 2]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it's possible to calculate the correct symbol to be printed at every position, so that the drawing part of the previous function could be written as

```
for (int row = 0; row < side; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < side; ++col) {
        bool is_horizontal = 
            ( row < col  &&  col < side - row) ||
            ( side - row <= col  &&  col <= row );
        bool is_space =
            (row % 2  &&  is_horizontal)  ||
            (col % 2  &&  !is_horizontal);
        putchar(stroke[is_space]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The logic could be shrinked even further, implementing a sort of truth table, loosing some readability, though:

```
void draw_boxes(int n) {        
    const char truth_table[] = "# ##### #     # ";

    if ( n < 1 )
        return;

    int side = 4 * n - 1;

    for (int row = 0, r_row = side - 1; row < side; ++row, --r_row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < side; ++col) {
            unsigned index = (row % 2) << 3  // Is 'row' odd?
                ^ (row < col) << 2           // Is in the top right half?
                ^ (col > r_row) << 1         // Is in the bottom right half?
                ^ (col % 2);                 // Is 'col' odd?

            putchar(truth_table[index]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```